# Problem downloading a file to a specific directory in Linux using Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, linux, spring, selenium-webdriver

Currently I'm having a problem extracting a document using Selenium (4.5.3) for Spring in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)).

In my current implementation I tried to download the file to a specific directory as shown in my code

```
private ChromeDriver instantiateDriver(boolean headless) {
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
        co.addArguments("--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors",
                "--disable-extensions", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage");

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPath + File.separator + "myDirectory");
        prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", "Chrome PDF Viewer");
        prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", "True");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "False");
        co.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        co.setCapability("se:downloadsEnabled", true);
        if (headless)
            co.addArguments("--headless",
                    "--window-size=1920x1080)");
        ChromeDriver driver = null;
        try {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
        } catch (SessionNotCreatedException e) {
            log.error("driver had some problems initing...");
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

I had success doing this procedure in windows, but can’t seem to make it work for Linux. The variable downloadPath has the following format /myMainDirectory/files. I don’t have any errors but the file doesn’t appear in any directory (designated or default).

Comment: Try changing the downloadPath to absolute path e.g /home/<user>/<rest of the path>

Comment: Please update your question with `downloadPath` value and code output.